# Calculating time increments individually in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with user IDs all in one column and "time series" for each user, which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'time': [0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 10, 20, 30, 80], 'score': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
```

I want to calculate time differences for each user_id:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'time': [0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 20, 10, 50], 'score': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
```

I think np.diff would work if I could limit it to each user_id. This is my first question on StackOverflow, hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try, using `groupby` with `diff`, then fillna first NaN with current time value:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('user_id')['time'].diff().fillna(df['time'])
```

Output:

```
   user_id  time  score  diff
0        1     0      1   0.0
1        1     1      2   1.0
2        1     3      3   2.0
3        2     4      4   4.0
4        2     8      5   4.0
5        2    10      6   2.0
6        3    20      7  20.0
7        3    30      8  10.0
8        3    80      9  50.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This is my first experience, and a very positive one!

Comment: @DenisKazakov You're welcome.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.